# Dragon breaking sound barriers unaided

Tags: creature-design, dragons, flight

Taking several notable real life inspirations from the animal kingdom I like to design a realistic Dragon towering any creature ever lived but has a nasty habit of generating sonic boom every where in its wake. What are the prerequisites my Dragon have to evolve in order to attain supersonic flight?

I think it's must have close to a mammal blood circulation to supply ample oxygen to its already effective muscular system and is warm blooded like a cheetahs to give it energy for sudden rush of adrenaline, a crocodiles eyelids to cover it eyes, and so on. My concern is that this colossal winged breast would be too heavy and its skeletal structure have to be augmented naturally through evolution but I have no clues how any animal can survive unhurt after performing such a earth shattering feat any ideas? No tech pls and absolutely no thunderpants!

Comment: In addition to a dragon already being implausible; the speed of sound is 3 times higher than the speed of a peregrine falcon in full dive and that's the fastest known avian in the world.

Comment: It would require magic/handwaving or jet propulsion. See http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/is-a-jet-dragon-possible?rq=1

Comment: The fuel for the jet propulsion could be released from special glands and be natural.

Comment: Magical Enhancements allowed, or does it need to be 100% natural?

Comment: @DanSmolinske please apply magic sparingly else I'm a strong believer of life will find a way.

Comment: Yeah I think "magic did it" would be a bad answer, but I also doubt you're going to get this 100% naturally.  I have an idea, will try and flesh it out.

Comment: One of the biggest obstacles would most likely be the temperature. Especially around it's snout and the leading edges of it's wings. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodynamic_heating)

Comment: "a realistic Dragon towering any creature ever lived" This sounds like a tall order. [Blue whales have been known to weigh 190,000 kg, African elephants 10,000 kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_organisms#Animals), and male adult [giraffes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe#Appearance_and_anatomy) stand up to about six meters tall. All of these species are around in our world today. You are going to have an awfully hard time getting either of those off the ground in a believable, naturally evolved manner.

Comment: By "unaided", do you mean with or without Gravity?  Because planes, aided by gravity in Power Dives, were able to break the sound barrier, long before Chuck Yeager flew the X-1, but that was not counted as "unaided".  With gravity, something the size and weight you suggest could conceivably do it in such a power dive, though surviving it might be difficult...

Comment: Gravity is part of nature so definitely applicable do you wish to launch the dragon into low earth orbit similar to Zibbobz's answer?

Comment: "I know dragons are supposed to breathe fire, but doesn't it come out the other end?"

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I'd be very surprised indeed if a creature capable of propelling itself in flight could, in an unpowered dive in a normal atmosphere, get close to the sound barrier.  I can't be bothered to do the maths to work out the terminal velocity, but Felix Baumgartner had some rather special gear, a very high starting position and no wings.  Wings would add drag area and wouldn't be a usable form of propulsion at such high speeds; the wings required to fly to very high altitudes would be huge (+O₂ requirement).

Comment: you could adjust the density or composition of the atmosphere... if the air were thinner, you could go faster with less effort. unless, of course, it was an air-breathing engine er... dragon.

Comment: Tolkin's dragon had enough wisdom to talk and converse with humans. Just a gentle reminder.

Comment: @ChrisH We are already talking about how to design a creature so that it can break the sound barrier.  My point being that it's a *lot* easier with gravity-assist than without. Both Peregrine Falcons and Swifts achieve their highest speeds with the assistance of gravity and planes were able to break the sound barrier with gravity assistance long before they could without it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, yes, but I'm saying that gravity assist+wing-powered-flight won't do it, you need a power dive that doesn't add drag or rely on pulling the wings forward again.

Comment: I think all of you are very excited for witnessing a Dragon doing re-entry from space I need to know if upon reaching terminal velocity how can it remains conscious and in control to apply brake without destroying itself midair or leaving a crater? A certain species of whale dived into the abyss in which such depth crushed even current submersible to feast not to contemplate suicide! (beaching)

Comment: @ChrisH The wings need not create too much drag, as they could be folded in for dive, as falcons do. It seems to me that a very streamlined, yet very heavy dragon with a very low drag coefficient may be able to reach very high speeds in a dive.

Comment: @Burki Temperature shouldn't be a problem at all for dragons. In the movie of The Hobit, Smaug was completely submerged in molten gold (> 1,000 C), and suffered not the slightest harm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Dragons would need to have a reason to be supersonic in order to evolve to do so.**

Being able to fly at supersonic speeds will have incredibly high metabolic and structural costs for the dragon. In order for one to evolve these traits, we need to answer the following question: why do supersonic dragons produce more offspring than non-supersonic dragons?

If supersonic flight doesn't get more food, or more mates, dragons won't evolve it. Similar non-supersonic dragons would outcompete the supersonic ones, since they would require far less food.

In nature, nothing else flies supersonic, and supersonic flight won't be worth its calories if its used to catch cattle or ponies or other such animals. That's not to say that it couldn't be useful, though. Dragons have projectile weapons, so if dragons mostly fight against other dragons, supersonic flight could give them a key edge in dogfighting, especially since the dragon they were closing in on wouldn't be able to hear them coming.

**Dragons would need to consume incredibly high caloric density food in order to evolve to be supersonic.**

It takes a *lot* of energy for an aircraft to reach supersonic speeds, probably more than an animal could obtain eating other animals. If dragons fly at supersonic speeds, they'll need to consume something more energetically dense. Something like oil.

If dragons consume oil from naturally occurring sources, they could directly burn this in an internal jet engine in order to achieve supersonic flight.

**The Ecology of Dragons**

Dragons are large creatures that eat oil. They both extract calories from it, and produce refined fuel which they burn in their engines. These engines resemble a pulse-jet engine, and are primarily comprised of carbon fibers and thermally resistant graphites which the dragons synthesize from their food.

Naturally occurring oil, of course, is rare, and as a result, dragons have become incredibly territorial. They've got large, stiff bodies covered in smooth scales to reduce their drag, and can launch flaming globs of tar at one another mid flight. Large dragons can fly at supersonic speeds, which gives them maneuvering advantages in their aerial fights over oil-rich territory. Because their bodies are stiffened for high speed flight, they can't turn their heads very much, so skill in dogfighting is key for dragons to protect their territories.

These supersonic dogfights, of course, are necessarily short, as the thick scales of graphite that dragons grow on the leading edges of their wings and along their heads slowly ablate during supersonic flight. Dragons prefer to cruise at fast subsonic speeds and use their size and breath weapons to dispatch smaller challengers if possible, rapidly accelerating into the supersonic regime only when absolutely necessary to outmaneuver an opponent. These graphite scales also provide a measure of resistance against the breath weapons of other dragons.

Larger dragons can grow these heat shields faster and thicker than smaller dragons. As this gives the largest of these creatures a major edge in combat, evolution has driven these majestic creatures to grow to truly colossal sizes.

Comment: Good answer. Could you also think up a solution to the enormous thermal effects on leading edges in the drtagon's structure? Maybe large blood vessels in those regions to provide some sort of liquid cooling?

Comment: Alternatively, they could grow their own heatshields.

Comment: First criterion - the flame comes out the other end.

Comment: Indeed dragons do have a high metabolic cost: [over 600,000 calories a day](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10098/294)!!

Comment: Partial reason to evolve supersonic flight: ***no one can hear you coming***.

Comment: And then humans get into conflict with dragons over oil reserves. Add intelligence to the dragons, and things get interesting.

Comment: This answer reminds me of this humorous [essay](http://www.rusf.ru/english/loginov/books/eurdrag.htm) about how European dragons were really huge insects eating oil and pyrite to fuel their flying and firebreathing.

Comment: Naturally occurring oil — whales, rather than petroleum. Maybe big, seamonster whales?

Comment: Doesn't a dragon having an 'engine' essentially equivalent to "thunderpants"?

Comment: Another reason for dragons to go supersonic would be if a sonic boom was criteria for sexual selection - the dragons that make more or louder booms have more offspring.

Comment: I would suggest that a dragon may have as much reason to fly super-sonic as a human. Jets are made to fly super-sonic to be able to launch surprise attacks, and to avoid being attacked while in-flight. Both traits that I imagine would be extremely useful also to a dragon.

Answer (score 14):

The real issue behind your dragon problem isn't biological - it's mechanical.  The fastest  animal on earth is the Peregrine Falcon, which can only reach speeds of 389 KM/H while going at full-dive, which is several magnitudes slower than needed.   Simply put, an organic life form could not possibly achieve supersonic speed...

Unless they can make it into space.

Skydiver Felix Baumgartner have been well-documented to have broken the sound barrier simply by falling high enough - 24 miles up to be exact.  If your dragon can get itself that high up in the first place, all it would take is falling down, then catching itself before it breaks every bone in its body.

The problems your dragon would face trying to do this are:

- Getting that high up in the first place
- Surviving the atmospheric climb without externals
- Breaking its fall in a non-catastrophic way

Let's get our dragon into space first.

### **Getting Up Into Space**

If your dragon is Titan-levels of large, and you don't mind it leaving a crater behind when it launches into the air, it could simply push itself off the ground and, with a light enough body, accelerate itself up 24 miles high.  This would require an enormous amount of energy, but we're not looking to solve the ecosystem problem of a giant dragon - we just want to get it into space.

Another option, that could pair well with the above solution, would be hydrogen gas pockets that allow it to float up into the atmosphere (and would explain where it gets all that fire, if it can breath fire that is).  You wouldn't make it all the way up with just hydrogen, but coupled with a good launch, you might just make it high enough.

This would also have to be aided by wings to give them additional thrust(origin of their wings I will get to later) since any momentum that could solely carry them up that far would create a sonic boom on takeoff (Not that this would be necessarily a *bad* side-effect).

Getting both of these would be evolutionarily unlikely - you would need a strong food chain full of high-caloric prey, coupled with a reason to float and have such strong legs.  Fortunately, I have an idea...

### **Surviving In Space**

Your dragon will need to not only survive in the incredibly low-atmosphere of space, but also survive the lack of oxygen involved with being so high in the first place. Evolution-wise, there's one option that might give you both of these at once: Deep sea hibernating ancestors.

Deep sea ancestors on the scale of Giant Squids would give you giant, strong dragons with especially strong legs that would be increasingly strong outside of the high pressures of the ocean, and hibernating beneath the sea, perhaps after feasting on giant squids, would give them a reason to survive without oxygen.

It even suggests a means by which this behavior was evolutionarily chosen for - launching themselves from the sea floor, the faster and stronger dragons, who could also handle the rapid change in pressure, could more easily catch Giant Squid the faster they can go.  Some dragons may have even figured out that they can get a better chance of catching them on the return-trip, which would lead them to trying to jump higher and higher, until eventually they evolve the ability to survive breaching the water, then as they move onto land, learn to use their strong legs to leap into space.

### **Surviving the Drop**

This is your biggest challenge - to explain how a dragon that evolved from a sea creature would survive a 24-mile drop.  Their initial sheer resistance to pressure (possibly owing to their scales) helps, but they'll need SOME way to catch themselves as they break the sound barrier.

Fortunately, being from the sea gives them one unique feature that could help them with this - Fins, or evolutionarily speaking, evolved wings.  Originally used to slow themselves back down after catching a squid, they could use them to catch the air and shift their direction mid-flight, so that their momentum is reduced and redirected in a wholly non-catastrophic, and entirely sound-barrier-breaking way.

There you have it - dragons that leap into space and come crashing down at supersonic speeds, evolved from giant sea-dwelling predators that ate giant squids literally for breakfast.

Comment: +1 I cannot think of any way for a non-jet powered entity to break the sound barrier besides using gravity to pull them to the ground like this.

Comment: I like the idea of dragons that can move effortlessly between sea, surface, sky, and space. Also, being streamlined for underwater movement would make them look really, really cool.

Comment: Never mind the energy, launching your self 24km into the sky with out accelerating while airborne requires you to leave the ground at a minimum of ~686m/s (calculated not taking air resistance into account) which is about twice the speed of sound. You would defiantly require some propulsion on the way up, or you've solved the problem simply by taking off :)

Comment: @WilSelwood That I believe is where their hydrogen sacs would give them some assistance. Though....admittedly they would probably have to make a sonic boom on their way up to even POTENTIALLY make one on their way down, so it's not a non-issue.  I've edited in a potential solution.  Though if you don't mind suspending disbelief even further, sonic booms on takeoff would not be a **bad** side-effect.

Comment: I was going to comment here but it turned into its own answer. Using a kelp like plant with hydrogen pockets to ride up. Rather than the dragon having rather risky gas sacks of its own.

Comment: Very interesting idea I have never thought that giant squid are so eager to took to the air and so desperate that they are willing to brave re-entry just to feast. (Regrettably this site permit only 1 upvote per account)

Comment: And Sonic booms for the equivalent of fishing with explosives. Dive, kill fish, feast on floating dead fish.

Comment: "Simply put, an organic life form could not possibly achieve supersonic speed..." -> Why?

Comment: @Mnementh The sheer energy cost of accelerating that much would be too great.  The fastest any organism can manage on its own is the Peregrine Falcon in full dive, and that's using gravity, not any thrust of its own, to achieve that speed.

Comment: That's correct, but not a problem of organic beings alone, breaking the sound barrier needs lots of energy, also for aircrafts. That is not limited to organisms, hence my question. The energy needed is by the way so high, because of air resistance, in vacuum it would need much less energy (while wings on the other hand would not work).

Comment: @Mnementh I'm more referring to existing organic life forms.  I'll clarify that later when I have more time.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I think a smaller dragon would be more likely to achieve these high flight speeds.  If for no other reason than it can help them escape larger dragons and can be used as a weapon.

I don't think the dragon could reach these speeds by flapping their wings alone, especially since most dragons would already need magic just to fly because of their size.  But if they are very fast and can fly high into the stratosphere, then turn down and dive, they might be able to break the sound barrier with just a little handwavium.  This could have come about partly from escaping larger dragons, (fly higher than they can) and then attacking either prey or as another defense against the larger predators.

If it was used as an attack dive they might need reinforced heads and necks, but the sonic boom would really mess up another flying creature or any other creature it passes near.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to post this as a comment on @Zibbobz's answer, however it kind of grew to being its own answer.

If there was some local fauna which was kind of like kelp. With pockets of hydrogen gas to help hold it's self up. The plant would have evolved this to help them scatter their seeds or pollen over a very large area.

When the dragon wants to go hunting it grabs hold of lots of these. Cuts them free of the ground and floats up, up and away. These plants will have evolved to have very stretchy gas sacks so they can reach higher altitudes. (a normal weather balloon can stretch four times its size during flight[1](http://www.diyspaceexploration.com/introduction-to-high-altitude-balloons/)) During the early phase of the flight the dragon takes many deep breaths to oxygenate its blood and then holds its breath once it passes out of the range where it can breath. Whales can hold their breath for up to 90 minutes.

Once the dragon is high enough or the balloon/kelp pops it drops down in a very stream lined shape with its wings folded back. It is still holding its breath. Here it will break the sound barrier. The pray it is falling on will not see or hear it coming. The pray is going to have to give it a huge amount of energy. This has to feed a dragon after all.

As the dragon needs to slow down it first goes from noes down to nose level then slowly expands its wings. Hopefully managing to glide out of the fall before it splatters its self into the ground.

The highly flammable plants may be a problem with this plan. Maybe need to explain that the plants seeds can be activated by fire and thus why they are around fire breathing dragons. We are trying to deal with big dragons, some amount of hand waving is required to deal with the square/cubed law.

Comment: It's not a bad form of propulsion, though it does break the "unaided" requirement.

Comment: True, but its not tech or underpant as the question requested.

Comment: Fair.  +1 For some very creative thinking.

Comment: Still, with earth athmospheric pressure the falling speed would max out below supersonic speed. Decreasing the air pressure though would it also make easier to reach higher speeds in horizontal flight.

Comment: Are you sure? Wolfram alpha lists the terminal velocity of a blue whale as 5.2Km/s way way over the sound barrier. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=terminal+velocity+of+an+blue+whale Seeing as he said these things tower over any creature that's ever lived. A blue whale seemed like a reasonable example

Answer (score 1):

What if the dragons utilize their standard, magically hot fire to **modify themselves** for supersonic flight?

Arcane knowledge of metallurgy and surgery, passed down through the ages, is used to augment their bones with titanium alloys bathed in dragonfire, strengthening their frames for the ordeal while being hollowed to reduce weight.  Scales are reshaped and smoothed to reduce friction, and re-enforced on the leading edge to take the brunt of supersonic flight.

Tanks are added to artificial structures, and the dragons use magic to purify and store enhanced rocket fuel that they then use to literally rocket themselves to supersonic speeds.

Comment: "Steampunk cyborg dragon surgeon" has a pretty nice ring to it.

Comment: To go through such an ordeal just for that ordeal these dragons definitely earns my respect and Wolverine (X-men) should be ashamed of himself for relying on Blackbird to accomplish speed of sound.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned about the boom and do not necessarily need flight, you could consider different methods of creating a sonic boom.

One scenario that is not so far-fetched and actually might have happened is that dinosaurs with very long tails could have flicked them like a bullwhip, accelerating the tip of their tails to the speed of sound.

[Here](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/12/02/science/did-dinosaurs-break-the-sound-barrier.html) is an article from '97 about a paleontologist discussing whether it is possible.

Comment: This isn't an unheard of form of attack even today: Pistol Shrimp quite effectively use sonic weapons underwater, though they are much smaller and have the high viscosity of water working for them - a larger creature like dinosaurs, or dragons, could potentially get a large enough snap to mimic something on a larger, land-based scale.  Perhaps by whipping their massive tail as you suggested, or as an alternative, clapping their wings sharply together.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the speed of a perigrine falcon as 1/3rd the speed of sound.

We know that the force of acceleration is proportional to mass.

We know that the force opposing this (air resistance) is proportional to surface area and the square of velocity.

We can rearrange those to say that velocity is proportional to SQRT(mass/surface area).

We can say that mass is proportional to density and wingspan^3.

We can say that surface area is proportional to wingspan^2.

So velocity =k x SQRT(density x wingspan).

We can define density to be density(any animal) = density(peregrine falcon) x y.

using symbols v = p(falcon) x y.

Where y is the density of the animal divided by density of a falcon.

So v = k x SQRT(pyw).

For a peregrine falcon, v = 1/3 speed of sound = 113 m/s. Where; p=1,w =1.

113 = k x SQRT(1).

So k = 1.

For a dragon:

v = 113 SQRT(xw).

Lets set w = 30 meters, and density double that of a falcon, x=2.

v = 113 SQRT(60) = 875 = nearly triple that of sound.

Assuming you have solved the problem of how such a big and heavy animal flies, then getting them to dive much faster than sound is trivial.

The bigger they are, the faster they fall.

Answer (score 0):

A creature meeting your size, speed, and strength requirements would have to be composed of extremely lightweight tissues, most notably including the skeleton (which must be able to handle the physical stresses of accelerating to supersonic speeds rapidly) and muscles (which must be able to convert the creature's biochemical or magical energies into mechanical energy efficiently, rapidly, and at high volume).

The most "realistic" way I could imagine all of these requirements being satisfied is if your dragon looks like a blimp: a giant sack of air that moves short distances by flapping its wings, and naturally floats in the air because its body density is about equal to the surrounding air density. Such a creature might achieve supersonic speeds by rapidy forcing most of the air in its body cavity through a small opening to create jet propulsion. This would also cause the creature to deflate to a narrow, streamlined shape that's more aerodynamic for long, straight flight paths.

We could go into further technical detail, but as you can see the result is a bit ridiculous. Really what I'm saying is you need a fart dragon.

Comment: +1 if the lift gas is hydrogen or methane and the blimp dragon has to ignite it to accelerate to supersonic speeds.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the big problem here is air resistance. Falling objects top out at a speed of somewhat above 500 km/h because of air resistance. Sound of speed is 1200 km/h. So it would need immense energy to speed up above that limit. Luckily there is an easy way around it: just decrease the air pressure. To get still enough oxygen to support big creatures the percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere has to be increased. But all that are possibilities and would it make easier to achieve higher speeds. Still, [most birds reach their highest velocity in dives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_by_flight_speed), so you may want to let the dragon break to supersonic speeds while make an diving attack from a higher flight position.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: This is far too simplistic. There is no standard speed for a falling object. It depends a great deal on density, shape etc. If a dragon was heavy enough, and streamlined enough, there's no reason why it couldn't go supersonic in a dive. I didn't down-vote, but this is probably why you received a down-vote.

Comment: Mass is irrelevant for falling speeds. Bigger mass means bigger force of gravitational pull, but also bigger momentum. That's why gravitational pull of earth is a constant given as acceleration (9,81 m/s2). Shape is more important, as it influences air resistance. But either way, at some point air resistance cancels out gravitational pull. The best form is similar to a raindrop and the 500 km/h max speed I looked up back then I answered the question. The dragon can produce own acceleration, but the same problem with air resistance. Birds combine fall and flight for reaching high speeds.

Comment: This is incorrect. Mass is very relevant for falling speed. More specifically density. Think of a polystyrene ball compared to a canon ball. Which will fall faster? A raindrop isn't the fastest object, because water isn't particularly dense. A lead ball will fall much faster than a raindrop. If you look it up, you'll find that density is required to calculate terminal velocity.

Comment: "A biography by Galileo's pupil Vincenzo Viviani stated that Galileo had dropped balls of the same material, but different masses, from the Leaning Tower of Pisa to demonstrate that their time of descent was independent of their mass."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall

Comment: Mass is required to calculate terminal velocity. https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/termv.html

Comment: The Leaning Tower of Pisa is only 57m high. This is not high enough for most objects to reach terminal velocity.

Comment: Here's another resource, which may be a bit easier to understand... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity

Comment: Yeah, mass is included in terminal velocity, as higher mass means air resistance has less of an effect, but it does not result in higher acceleration.